# no application found error, when running python file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

pretty new to python. I got some gifted some code to try and tidy up and get working. whenever I try to run the code that populates the database ( python log_parser.py -d plp_database.sqlite -l \anonned_logs_DANW)
I get a error

```
Reading 


C:\Users\name\Downloads\plp11\plp\anonned_logs_DANW/csquery.stats.20200101

-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 519, in __get__
   return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 981, in get_app
   raise RuntimeError(
 RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or 
 push an application context. See http://flask- 
 sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
 (venv)
```

- The create_app/**init**.py file is below

  ````
  from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
  from flask_migrate import Migrate
  from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

  __version__ = (1,0,0, "dev")

  db = SQLAlchemy()


  def create_app(testing=None):
      app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
      if testing is None:
          app.config.from_object('config.Config')
      else:
          app.config.from_object('config.TestConfig')
      db.init_app(app)


   with app.app_context():
      from . import routes, models
      db.create_all()
      migrate = Migrate(app, db)
      bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
      return app ```
  ````

I’ve tried looking over the **init**.py file where the above code is located but cant see anything obviously  amiss.

Ive compared it with Flask documentation and it seems right although there could be a glaring mistake.

I have no clue in how to fix this so any help would be appreciated.
if anymore info is needed let me know and ill add it in.

**edit**

```
plp
..application
....static
....templates
....__init__.py
....models.py
....routes.py
..config.py
..ingestor.py
..log_parser.py
..parser_config
..wsgi.py
```

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import re
from application import db
from hashlib import sha256
from distutils import util
from application.models import LogData, CanonicalQuery, CronLog

class Ingestor:
  def __init__(self, logs_path):
    self.logs_path = os.path.abspath(logs_path)
    print(logs_path)
    print("ive just printed the logs path")

  def list_logs(self):
    for file in self.get_logs():
      print (file)


  def get_logs(self):
    files = os.listdir(self.logs_path)
    return files


  def _get_start_line(self,file_path):**this is where it appears to fall over**

    print("Reading %s" % file_path)

    cronlog = CronLog.query.filter_by(file_path=file_path).first()

    if cronlog:
      return cronlog.last_entry
    return 0
    


  # return 
  def canonicalise(self, sql_query):
    tmp = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", sql_query)
    tmp = re.sub(r"'.*?'", "@QSTR", tmp)
    tmp = re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "@NUM", tmp)
    
    tmp = re.sub(r"@QSTR(\s*,\s*@QSTR)+", "@QSTR_LIST", tmp)
    tmp = re.sub(r"@NUM(\s*,\s*@NUM)+", "@NUM_LIST", tmp)
    tmp = re.sub(r"[Ii][Nn] \(\s*@QSTR\)", "IN (@QSTR_LIST)", tmp)
    tmp = re.sub(r"[Ii][Nn] \(\s*@NUM\)", "IN (@NUM_LIST)", tmp)

    # Query db for instance of object
    query = CanonicalQuery.query.filter_by(con_sql=tmp).first()

    if query:
      return query.id
    else:
      sql = CanonicalQuery(con_sql=tmp)
      db.session.add(sql)
      db.session.commit()
      return sql.id
      

  def add_data(self):
    # get a list of all of the files
    files = self.get_logs()
    # parse all files to csv objects
    for file in files:
      # we can check if the file has changed before we try and parse it by checking the file checksum(sha256).
      file_path="%s/%s" % (self.logs_path,file)
      with open(file_path, "r") as csvfile:
        line_total = self._get_start_line(file_path)
        line_count = 0
        try:
          reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',') # ignore the inital space if found
          for num, row in enumerate(reader):
            if num > line_total:
              db.session.add(
                LogData(
                time=datetime.strptime(row['Time'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                user=row['User'],
                host=row['Host'],
                duration=row['Duration'],
                recs_selected=row['Recs selected'],
                recs_returned=row['Recs returned'],
                recs_examined=row['Recs examined'],
                bytes_read=row['Bytes read'],
                index_seeks=row['Index seeks'],
                batch_seeks=row['Batch seeks'],
                lookup_duration=row['Lookup duration'],
                base_raw_duration=row['Base/raw duration'],
                sort_duration=row['Sort duration'],
                error=util.strtobool(row['Error']),
                server_used=row['Server used'],
                action=row['Action'],
                _case=row['Case'],
                sql_query_id=self.canonicalise(row['SQL'])
                )
              )
            line_count = num
          db.session.commit()
        except KeyError:
          print ("%s - is not a vaild log file skipping...." % file_path)
        print("Entries iterated %s entries total %s " % (line_count, line_total))
        self.update_log(file_path, line_count)

  def update_log(self, file_path, last_entry):
    with open(file_path,"rb") as file_data:
      data = file_data.read()
      data_checksum = sha256(data).hexdigest()
      # Check if entry exsists
      cronlog = CronLog.query.filter_by(file_path=file_path).first()
      if cronlog:
        cronlog.date_parsed = datetime.now()
        cronlog.last_entry = last_entry
        cronlog.checksum = data_checksum
      else:
        # if no log exsits
        db.session.add(
          CronLog(
            date_parsed=datetime.now(),
            last_entry=last_entry,
            file_path=file_path,
            checksum=data_checksum
          )
        )
        db.session.commit()
```

marked in bold is where i think its falling over to.
the log_parser and ingestor files are the two main backend app files.

Comment: Can you share the project structure and its content? What is the __init_.py and the app.py?

Comment: it would appear that its falling over on its first interaction with the database in the ingestor file